# Does OpenCV with Python require X Windows?

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to run a simple OpenCV python script that uses the samples/python2/facedetect.py example, but instead of running in a loop, I just want it to detect a face, and then write the image.

Essentially, I changed cv2.imshow to cv2.imwrite, and it worked fine on Windows.

When I try the same thing on Linux (Debian), I get Xwindows errors like:

```
import: unable to grab mouse `': Resource temporarily unavailable @ error/xwindow.c/XSelectWindow/9007.
from: can't read /var/mail/video
from: can't read /var/mail/common
./facedetect.py: line 7: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./facedetect.py: line 7: `def detect(img, cascade):'
```

I don't want any windows to be drawn, all I want is for the code to open a jpg, detect the face, and write a new jpg.  Does OpenCV require X windows?  I went through the code, but was unable to identify a specific line of code that needed X windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have just given your program as input to the shell. You need to add a hashbang line like `#!/usr/bin/python` as the first line of your program file. Or invoke it as `python ./facedetect.py`

Comment: Thank you, this was the root cause.  Would you mind explaining what from the error messages tipped you off that this was the problem?  I'm still new to all this, so I'm not sure how you figured that out.  Thanks!

Comment: 1. I recognized which programs had been ran; `import` is screen grabbing program from imagemagick; `from` is a program that "prints names of those who have sent mail". And those would have only been ran if the file had been given as input to the shell. 2. I've done this myself.